# Can I get metadata for a namespace?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, metadata

If I put metadata in a namespace declaration:

```
(ns 
^{:doc "Myspace documentation"}
myspace
)
```

can I get it ? I tried `(meta myspace)`, `(meta #'myspace)` but I can't get it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are currently in that namespace, you can do this

```
myspace=> (meta *ns*)
{:doc "Myspace documentation"}
```

If you are NOT in the namespace, you can use [find-ns](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/find-ns)

```
foo=> (meta (find-ns 'myspace))
{:doc "Myspace documentation"}
```